# UIView Animations not playing sometimes (going to end state immediately)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

In my app I have a camera and another view controller that I present when the photo is taken. It seems that when I move the camera too fast when I take the photo, the animations stop working (even the segues back to the original UITabBar, that precedes the camera). I am not sure if this is related to CPU usage and there not seems to be a pattern here. Sometimes, only taking pictures make it behave this way. My animations are mainly this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in                      

//buttons.alpha = 1 or 0
//buttonA.center.x += 100

}, completion: nil)
```

in ViewDidLoad there are only a few alpha change values inside animation. Most of the other animations blocks are when buttons are clicked. The most interesting thing though is that if I dismiss the view controller and come back to the camera, sometimes the behavior persists and sometimes not, like as if there is no pattern at all. When the behavior persists, it affects even the segues out of the camera view controller itself ( and the other parts of the tabBar that are the main view of the app - like in Instagram, for instance). Thus, it affects the whole app. What do you guys think would be the cause of this odd behavior?
Objective-C code is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call animate code in the `ViewDidLoad:` portion of the view controller lifecycle. At this point the view has finished loading but it may or may not have appeared on screen yet. There's `viewWillAppear:` which you can insert your animation in and at that point, when the view has appeared, it will perform the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try viewDidApear? I'm not sure that the view has actually been added to the view hierarchy in either viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. The only downside is you can't assume it will only be called once in the viewController's life cycle.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and didn't solve either. This seems to be a problem with memory or CPU usage since this error is more frequent when I put the app to test. For instance, If I tap on the screen to focus and move the camera fast and tap the button to take a picture immediately, the odd behavior happens. It seems that it is related to sending too many process that the animations somehow do not get to be played accordingly.